# Send email notification failure Azure data factory Pipeline not working (Web Job)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, email-notifications, webjob, azure-adf

I have a pipeline where the following activities takes place
Lookup-> Lookup ->ForEach->(Stored Procedure)-> Send Success Email/ Send Failure Email
[image]

Once the pipeline successfully completed its execution, I see a successful email in my inbox, however for any reason the foreach activity fails I don't see a Failure Email.
Inside Foreach Stored procedure might get executed dynamically sometimes based on N number of times.

Inside foreach I have only one activity (Stored Procedure execution).

This is the configuration for Email Failure message, I do try to pull the dynamic error message, so I have added a code as **"ErrorMessage":"@{activity('Lookup').output.message}"**, It shows me
Error.Message is not a property, Moreover I wanted to get a Failure email
[image]
Configuration for Success Email, works perfectly fine
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the above task by modifying my pipeline with
**Lookup->Lookup->ForEach(Stored Procedure -> If Condition-> WaitTrue/WaitFalse -> WebJob to send email which I have added to a separate pipeline)**
[image]
[image]

Under if condition activity checking for Error status from previous activity

```
@contains(activity('Load Tables').Status,'Succeeded')
```

In case of Failure, the status would be Error and catching the message as

```
"errorMessage":"@{activity('Load Tables').Error.message}"
```